# How could one setup a layout for a dictionary? (if possible)

Tags: header-footer, margins, book-design, columns

A friend asked me if I knew any free software for creating dictionaries - which is good at saving space (reduce total number of pages).

Example:

[image]

I suppose this might be possible in LaTeX. Thankful for any suggestions or pointers.

Comment: For adding a dictionary-style running head that shows the first/last entry per page, it would be easiest to input the dictionary items (`\dict` in @Tobi's answer) as some form of sectional command (like `subsubsection`, say). Then it should be possible to use information contained in [Chapters and verses of current page in header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26274/5764) to update these running headers automatically via the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess the sorting can be done with `xindy`, `glossaries`, `luatex` or something else. And maybe the entrys should come from a database.

The following could be first approach for the layout. Please note that this is a draft only!

- I used a narrow font to get as much as possible letters in one line
- I added a macro to format the single entries. That makes later changes very easy.
- I guess it would be a god practice to define more macros for other extras (like reference-signs etc.)
- Chapter thumbs (german *Daumenindex*, actual letter in the margin) can be generated with TikZ and `scrpage2` see http://www.komascript.de/node/200 for example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[%
    a5paper,
    fontsize=7.5pt,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% narrow font
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{helvet}

% layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    margin=1cm,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadings
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{0.8pt}
\setfootsepline{0.8pt}
\lehead{word}% first word on page
\rohead{word}% last word on page
\chead{W}% actual letter
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagination}{\sffamily}

% entry command
% \dict{<word>}{<gender>}{<text>}
\newcommand{\dict}[3]{%
    \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
    \textbf{\textsf{#1}} \textit{#2} #3
}

% testing
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\foreach \n in {1,...,200} {%
    \dict{word}{n}{Some text with mor explanations. Some text with mor explanations}%
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Information**

To get more information about using `scrpage2` for head and foot see [scrguien](http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) or [scrguide](http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf) in german. In the [printed version](http://www.dante.de/index/Literatur/KOMA-Script.html) (german) you can find even a tutorial about chapter thumbs.

Comment: @jac: You’re welcome! But I’d like to say again, that this is only a working basis an not a finished elaborate layout ;-) (see my update for additional links)

Comment: Is it possible to do one macro to manage the header automatically ?

Comment: @projetmbc: I guess it is. But I don’t know how … Since this question is for the layout you may ask a new question like “How to automate a dictionary (sorting, headers)?“

Comment: @projetmbc: A look at [Chapters and verses of current page in header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26274/chapters-and-verses-of-current-page-in-header) could help you on your way.