# How to sort the entries of a dictionary alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, dictionaries

This is a follow-up question to: [How to automate a dictionary (sorting, headers)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30947/885)

I was wondering if there is a way to sort the entries alphabetically in the following code.
I guess myself that `xindy`, `glossaries` or something similar should do the trick, but I don't know how to do that.
BTW, I'm using `XeLaTeX` on TL2012 on Win7 and my document is in Persian which is an RTL language and also, I'd prefer to do this without using additional packages.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}

% Headers and footers
    \fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}}

    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}}

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt}

% Entry command : \dict{<word>}{<gender>}{<text>}
    \newcommand{\dict}[3]{%
        \markboth{#1}{#1}%
        \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
        \textbf{\textsf{#1}} \textit{- #2 -} #3%
    }

    \pagestyle{fancy}

% For testing
    \usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\section*{A}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
    \dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
\end{multicols}


\section*{M}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{multicols}


\section*{Z}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
    \dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I should mention that I MUST only use `xindy`, because the Persian language has some problems with other programs such as `makeindex`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you prefer not to use any additional packages, but if no other answer suits you, here's how to do it using `glossaries` and `xindy`. First the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}

% Headers and footers
\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% For testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% The optional argument is in case you can't use the name as a label    
\newcommand{\dict}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}%
  {%
    name=#2,%
    symbol=#3,%
    description=#4,%
    #1%
  }%
  \glsadd{#2}%
}

\newglossarystyle{dict}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \section*{##1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \markboth{##2}{##2}%
    \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
    \textbf{\textsf{##2}} \textit{- ##4 -} ##3%
  }%
}%

\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\begin{document}

    \dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
    \dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
    \dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
    \dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}

\printglossary[style=dict]
\end{document}
```

To create the PDF you need to perform 3 steps:

1. Use PDFLaTeX as usual, e.g. `pdflatex myDoc.tex` from a terminal/command prompt or click the PDFLaTeX button on your front-end/text editor.
2. Either run the Perl script `makeglossaries myDoc` or explicitly call `xindy` (see [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms) for more details).
3. Repeat step 1.

Comment: In the manual You say that `\longnewglossaryentry` is preferred for long entries w/ >1 paragraphs/newlines, yet, `\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum` should have 5+5+4 `\par`s. How come the `\newglossaryentry` works and shows up just fine?

Comment: @vlg It's not a problem if the instances of `\par` are hidden from the key=value parser.

Answer (score 8):

A solution based on `makeindex`.

```
%%% test.tex %%%
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}   
    \usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}

% Headers and footers
    \fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}}

    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}}

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt}

% Entry command : \dictb{<word>}{<gender>}{<text>}
    \newcommand{\dictb}[3]{%
        \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
        \leavevmode
        \markboth{#1}{#1}%
        \textbf{\textsf{#1}} \textit{- #2 -} #3%
    }

    \pagestyle{fancy}  

% further formatting commands

\newenvironment{thedict}{}{}
\newenvironment*{dictsection}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}%
}{\end{multicols}}
\newcommand*{\dictitem}[4]{%
  \dictb{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dict}{%
  \begingroup
    \@sanitize
    \@dblarg\@dict
}
\def\@dict[#1]#2#3#4{%
    \index{#1|{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% For testing
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}  
    \dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
    \dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
    \dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
    \dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
    \dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
    \dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
    \dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
    \dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
    \dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}

\printindex

\end{document}
%%% test.tex %%%
```

The `.idx` file is generated with style `dict.ist`:

```
% Begin: Use characters not needed
encap '<'
level '>'
escape '['
quote ']'
% End: Use characters not needed
actual '|'
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\begin{dictsection}{"
heading_suffix "}"
group_skip "\n\\end{dictsection}\n"
preamble "\\begin{thedict}\n"
postamble "\n\\end{dictsection}\n\\end{thedict}\n"
item_0 "\n  \\dictitem"
delim_0 "{"
delim_t "}"
```

The idea is that the index string that is written by LaTeX starts with the sort key, then `|` follows as separator and than the stuff follows that is actually used and set. Features like encapsulating command for page numbers, index levels and quoting/escaping are not needed. Therefore `dict.ist` uses `<`, `>`, `[`, `]`. Replace these characters by characters not needed for the dictionary entries (I would use bytes `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03`, `0x04`, do not use multiple bytes (UTF-8)).

Also `\dict` is defined in such a way, that it reads its arguments verbatim and uses an optional argument for the sort key. The first mandatory argument is used as default for the optional argument (feature of `\@dblarg`).

Then `test.idx` looks like:

```
\indexentry{adequate|{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}}{1}
\indexentry{adhere|{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}}{1}
\indexentry{adherence|{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}}{1}
\indexentry{adhesion|{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}}{1}
\indexentry{adhesive|{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjacent|{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjective|{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjoin|{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjourn|{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjournment|{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjunt|{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}}{1}
\indexentry{adjust|{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}}{1}
\indexentry{main|{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}}{1}
\indexentry{material|{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}}{1}
\indexentry{mathematic|{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}}{1}
\indexentry{more|{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}}{1}
\indexentry{zebra|{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}}{1}
\indexentry{zero|{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}}{1}
```

`makeindex -s dict.ist test` generates `test.ind`:

```
\begin{thedict}
\begin{dictsection}{A}
  \dictitem{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}{1}
  \dictitem{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}{1}
  \dictitem{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}{1}
  \dictitem{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}{1}
  \dictitem{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}{1}
  \dictitem{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}{1}
\end{dictsection}
\begin{dictsection}{M}
  \dictitem{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}{1}
  \dictitem{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}{1}
  \dictitem{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}{1}
  \dictitem{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}{1}
\end{dictsection}
\begin{dictsection}{Z}
  \dictitem{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}{1}
  \dictitem{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}{1}
\end{dictsection}
\end{thedict}
```

Running the example, e.g.:

- `pdflatex test`
- Optionally, edit `dict.ist` to change the characters of the first four settings to 1-byte characters not needed.
- `makeindex -s dict.ist test`
- `pdflatex test`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but could you please tell me how I should run your code?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but there are two problem: 1- As I said before, I should use Xelatex to run my files. 2- Unfortunately, the Persian language has some problems with `makeindex`, so I have to use `xindy` instead of `makeindex`.

Comment: By the way, could you please explain more about "Edit `dict.ist` to change the HTML entities by the real bytes."? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Just use some characters that are not used in the dictionary, e.g. `encap 'ä'` or `level '§'`. `Makeindex` does not provide a method to disable these characters entirely.

Comment: I can't still run your code even using `makeindex`, because I don't know how to do "Edit `dict.ist` to change the HTML entities by the real bytes."