# Custom subsection without newline

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I've applied solution [Chapters and verses of current page in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26310/70881) into my bible style. It gives text like this  [image]

In above solution each verse is created by `\subsection` in new paragraph. I want to modify `\subsection` to prevent newline or paragraph. I expect result like below keeping chapter and verse numbers in header.  [image]

I tried with `\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]` but I don't know if it is possible to remove newline or par.

Comment: Isn't this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224154/27635 better?

Comment: @karlkoeller How I can print current chapter and verses at the top of page in this solution?